# How to do the mongorestore on another folder?

Tags: mongodb, command-line, command, command-prompt, mongorestore

I am trying to run a `mongorestore` on a dump in a folder in Documents through the command prompt, but it isn't recognized. I can only run it  from inside the mongodb's `bin` folder. How can I fix this?

```
model: mongorestore --gzip --archive=${BACKUP_FILE_GZ} --nsFrom "${DB_NAME}." --nsTo "${DB_NAME_RESTORE}."
```

Answer (score 0):

Either add mongodb bin folder to PATH variable or run from bin folder and give full path of dump folder

Answer (score 0):

use /dir option

Example:
 mongorestore /dir